# DateListLogLogPlot

Tags: date-and-time

The command completion feature in Version 10.0.1.0 shows a command DateListLogLog but there is no documentation and doesn't work.

Is this something that is going to be released in the near future and Wolfram inc got out of sync or does it actually work but with non-obvious syntax?

```
junk = {{{2005, 5, 27}, 106}, {{2014, 5, 30}, 5000}}
DateListLogPlot[junk]
DateListLogLogPlot[junk]
```

Comment: I just tried it again on V 10.01 and it works: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HdpmP.png) (at first I thought you did not the correct API). Can you try again after starting new kernel?

Comment: btw, there is no `DateListLogLogPlot` function in M? screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3qqLc.png)  so not sure how you ended up with that.

Comment: DateListLogPlot works. It is DateListLogLogPlot that apparently does not exist, even though the Command completion feature finds it.

Comment: `though the Command completion feature finds it.` on my system, as I show in the screen shot above, `DateListLogLogPlot` does not show up. Version 10.01 on windows, if it shows up on your system, this is a bug that should be reported to support@wolfram.com

Answer (score 1):

`DateListLogLogPlot` does not exist in my copy of *Mathematica*, version 10.0.1.0 on Windows 7 64-bit.

One possible explanation for the observed behaviour is as follows.  When I start in a fresh session, the symbol does not appear in the completion list:

[image: completion screenshot]

However, if I then type `DateListLogLogPlot` into a cell and evaluate it, then the symbol now appears as a valid completion:

[image: completion screenshot]

It is easy to test whether this theory is correct -- start a new *Mathematica* session and check as the first action whether `DateListLogLogPlot` appears in the completion list.

This sudden appearance of user symbols is normal behaviour.  Whenever an expression is evaluated, any symbols that appear in it are created if they do not already exist.  Once created, these user-defined symbols appear in the completion menus.  In the latter screenshot, notice how no information is available for `DateListLogLogPlot`.  The symbol is essentially empty -- it has no value, no definitions, and no usage information defined for it.

One could argue that such empty symbols should not appear in the completion lists but this would mean, for example, that many option names would not appear since they are empty symbols themselves.  Also, empty symbols are used frequently in purely symbolic expressions.

Comment: The above must have been what happened as there is no other way to explain it. May be symbols in other than System` context can be show in one color and everything else in another color! Or, add a small horizontal line between System names (shown first) then all symbols in other contexts below the line next. I think mixing System symbols with user defined symbols is not a good idea in the the command completion popup menu as it is the case now.